# How to sort matching filenames (without extension) from three folders to an arrayList

Tags: android, arraylist

I have an "Object" class that consist of one UUID and three strings
I then have three folder paths, two of which contains image and last of video.
All the files that "belong" to eachother has the same filename except extension (`.jpg`, `.mp4`)

How do i best sort through these folders and collect matching filenames+path for each of the values so i can create an instance of Signs with those values and then put that instance in an `ArrayList<Signs>` ?

Im kinda lost at this moment :)

```
 public class Signs {

    UUID id;
    String name;
    String videoURL;
    String imageURL;
    String illustrativeURL;

    public Signs(String name,String videoURL,String imageURL,String illustrativeURL){
        this.id = UUID.randomUUID();
        this.name = name;
        this.videoURL = videoURL;
        this.imageURL = imageURL;
        this.illustrativeURL = illustrativeURL;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getVideoURL() {
        return videoURL;
    }

    public void setVideoURL(String videoURL) {
        this.videoURL = videoURL;
    }

    public String getBitmapURL() {
        return imageURL;
    }

    public void setBitmapURL(String bitmapURL) {
        this.imageURL = bitmapURL;
    }

    public UUID getId() {
        return id;
    }

}
```

Here is the method i use in my class to look through folders based on set path to each of them.

```
   public ArrayList<Signs> getArrayOfSignsFromFolder(String imagePath,String videoPath,String illustrativePath){
    ArrayList<Signs> arrayOfSignItems = new ArrayList<Signs>();
    Signs sign;
    File imagedirectory = new File(imagePath);
    File videodirectory = new File(videoPath);
    File illustrativedirectory = new File(illustrativePath);

    File[] imageListing = imagedirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")){
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }});

    File[] videoListing = videodirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp4")){
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".mp4");
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }});

    File[] illustrativeListing = illustrativedirectory.listFiles(new FilenameFilter() {
        @Override
        public boolean accept(File dir, String name) {
            if(name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg")){
                return name.toLowerCase().endsWith(".jpg");
            }
            else{
                return false;
            }
        }});

    for (int i = 0; i < imageListing.length; i++){

    }

    if(imageListing != null)

    {
       // hmmmm......... Any suggestions how to handle this?
    }

    else{
        return null;
    }


    return arrayOfSignItems;

}
```

Comment: store all three File array in another File array and then extract file extension from the name when you are going to match its name. and do what you want after that.

Comment: I will look into your suggestion a bit later, thanks and if it works out ill be back with thumbsup and code

Comment: App crashing all over the place, so havent been able to test. But it sounds like the right way to handle it.